# How to make "val()" work in html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an online order form which works great! the only thing thats wrong is that i cant seem to find a way to send the input data from the text fields with Naam:, Adres: etc. (which is at the bottom of the code) i found out that i could use this code : `$("#txt_name").val();` but it does not work properly. And i don't really know in which function i have to pace de code. Can someone help me? i'm not very experienced with jquery.

[working website](http://wietskekoelma.com/test/highteabestellijst.html)

[javascript without the html](http://wietskekoelma.com/test/orderform.js)

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1048572) and [edit] the relevant parts of your code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have the following

```
$(".txt_name").val();
```

You are using . as a class selector, you should use

```
$("#txt_name").val();
```

With # as an id selector

The first one gives you an array because you are selecting multiple elements and the second one gives you an element. I testet it in the browser console and it returns the value of the `#txt_name` Naam, but the first one returns undefined since `.txt_name` does not exist.

The same applies to the other fields, give them and id and you can get their values the same way.

Answer (score 0):

$("#txt_name").val() should return a string which you can store in a variable of pass to a function.
if you want it to return something usefull "#txt_name" must be an input element or an element with a value attribute.

lets say you have a test inpu tag with the id="txt_name" 
 if a user writes something that elements value attribue will be that text, even if you dont see it on the tag itself.
so $("#txt_name").val() will return the value of the value attribute of the htmlElement.

Comment: but using $("#txt_name").val() is what i need to do right? I put it in the get_data(f) function (of the javascript) but than it does not work. And i really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: yes it should return a string of the input value (the text the user wrote). did you check for errors? maybe your code is not executing correct.

Comment: you can insert the following code to check (or use the debugger): console.log($("#txt_name").val()); tan when in the browser press f12 and watch the console.

Comment: it doesn't work.. am i puting it in the right function?

Comment: Why dont you post the script so we canwhat it is. Maybe you didnt load jquery properly . Check for errors